# Loading asset with custom extension not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to implement my first application in react-native and I need to open database from a static file saved in my project folder.

I read that i need to allow loading custom extensions files from assets so i added following fragment into my `app.json` file:

```
"packagerOpts": {
    "assetExts": ["sqlite", "db"]
},
```

Next I'm trying to import this static file with .sqlite or .db extension inside my App.js component in `componentDidMount()` method:

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
  await Expo.FileSystem.downloadAsync(
    Expo.Asset.fromModule(require("./assets/db/local.db")).uri,
    `${Expo.FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite/local.db`
  );

  SQLite.openDatabase("local.db");
};
```

but expo builder keep saying `Unable to resolve "./assets/db/local.db" from "App.js"`. Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 11):

The following code is from 2 answers above

create **metro.config.js** in project root directory:

```
const defaultAssetExts = require("metro-config/src/defaults/defaults").assetExts;

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    assetExts: [
      ...defaultAssetExts,
      // 3D Model formats
      "dae",
      "obj",
      "mtl",
      // sqlite format
      "db",
      "sqlite"
    ]
  }
};
```

Optionally install metro-dependency: `npm i metro-config --save-dev`

Comment: and exactly this does not work in my environment:

    "metro-config": "latest", 
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.5",

Answer (score 2):

I found that expo has some kind of bug but there is PR raised/approved for this one. For anyone who can't wait for official bug fix there is also workaround for this one:

Create a metro.config.js file with assetExts fixed the problem for me:

```
module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    assetExts: ["db", "mp3", "ttf"]
  }
}
```

and import this file lets say in your App.js? I'm now able to open SQLite database from file.

Comment: hi @sebinq: Do you have a complete code base anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

Go to node_modules metro-config defaults.js ad extend type to the assetExts section Done~

Comment: What happens if you reinstall and the `node_modules` folder refreshes/ is re-created...

Answer (score 2):

In Expo 40 - here was how I was able to get it running!
[Expo website source.](https://docs.expo.io/guides/assets/#customizing-supported-asset-extensions)

**Note** you'll have to put the files in the `assets` directory, and make sure your `app.json` specifies all of the needed extensions, mine includes everything: `"assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],`

First, I'll split it into two parts - getting Expo to work, then getting typescript to work.

Expo was simple, but only once I realized it was the issue. I followed the above guide. In summary:

1. `expo install @expo/metro-config`
2. create a `metro.config.js` and call the `push` method with whatever extension you are trying to add, in my case it was `md` (markdown):

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('@expo/metro-config');

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push('md');

module.exports = defaultConfig;
```

3. Reset cache on expo (shift + r in the terminal window running it, on Mac)

Typescript (4) was more documented but I did:

1. Create a declaration (`*.d.ts`) file, specifying markdown as a valid extension.
2. Made sure that file was in one of my `tsconfig.json`, `"include"` directories
3. Add that file to `typeRoot` under `compilationOptions` in `tsconfig.json`
4. import/require the `md` in my component

For me these steps were:

1. add file `./app/declaration.d.ts`
2. My `"include"` had the `app` directory in it, and looked like this:   `"include": ["App.js", "app", "test", "storybook"]`
3. I added this to `compilationOptions`: `"typeRoots":["./app/declaration.d.ts"],`
4. `import newborn from './../../../assets/resources/MY_MD_DOC.md'`

Tada!