# How to append extension in metro.config.js for Metro Bundler?

Tags: javascript, react-native, metro-bundler

I'm trying to bundle `markdown` files without creating much overhead (i.e. not adding them manually to the asset bundles in Xcode and Android Studio, not using 3rd party dependencies).

My idea was to allow `require()` to include them by adjusting the metro bundler settings in `metro.config.js`:

```js
/**
 * Metro configuration for React Native
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

module.exports = {
    transformer: {
        getTransformOptions: async () => ({
            transform: {
                experimentalImportSupport: false,
                inlineRequires: false,
            },
        }),
    },
    resolver: {
        assetExts: [`md`] // < include md
    }
};
```

Sadly metro bundler replaces the array of given defaults with what's set here.

I don't want to explicitly repeat the default asset extension list which lists about 20+ file extensions, especially since I want to stick to the defaults otherwise. See: https://github.com/facebook/metro/blob/master/packages/metro-config/src/defaults/defaults.js.

Appending to the array does not work, too.

Using RN 0.59.3.

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found the answer on how to include the defaults here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55118654/844907.

```js
/**
 * Metro configuration for React Native
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

// get defaults assetExts array
const defaultAssetExts = require("metro-config/src/defaults/defaults").assetExts;

module.exports = {
    transformer: {
        getTransformOptions: async () => ({
            transform: {
                experimentalImportSupport: false,
                inlineRequires: false,
            },
        }),
    },
    resolver: {
        assetExts: [
            ...defaultAssetExts, // <- array spreading defaults
            'md'
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you please help on this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625169/react-native-could-not-resolve-module-masked-view-from-react-navigation-stack

Answer (score 3):

Other way you could do this is use the same syntax as [react-native-svg-transformer](https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer#step-3-configure-the-react-native-packager)

1. Make metro.config.js asynchronous
2. call the getDefaultConfig
3. Pull off the assetExts key

Example

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('metro-config')

module.exports = (async () => {
    const {
        resolver: { assetExts },
    } = await getDefaultConfig()
    return {
        transformer: {
            getTransformOptions: async () => ({
                transform: {
                    experimentalImportSupport: false,
                    inlineRequires: false,
                },
            }),
        },
        resolver: {
            assetExts: [...assetExts, 'md'],
        },
    }
})()
```

Comment: Looks a bit nicer but doesn't really change the functionality: getting default config (asynchronously), setting transformation options and adding assets. Fun fact: Looking at the revision history they published the solution about the same week as I did. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

```
const {getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig} = require('@react-native/metro-config');
/**
 * Metro configuration
 * https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration
 *
 * @type {import('metro-config').MetroConfig}
 */
const config = async () => {
  const defaultConfig = await getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
  const {
    resolver: {sourceExts, assetExts},
  } = defaultConfig;

  return mergeConfig(defaultConfig, {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
      getTransformOptions: async () => ({
        transform: {
          experimentalImportSupport: false,
          inlineRequires: true,
        },
      }),
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],
    },
  });
};
module.exports = config;
```

**This works on RN 0.72.3**

Good luck